# Rails 3; only run coffeescript if DB flag is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have the following in my view:

## event.html.erb

```
 <%- if(@event.requires_registration?) -%>
          <div class="form-group registration_form">
            <%= form_tag(register_learner_path, {remote: true}) do -%>
              <p>
              <%= label_tag :email %>
              <%= text_field_tag :email %>
              <p/>
              <p>
              <%= label_tag "First Name" %>
              <%= text_field_tag :first_name %>
              <p/>
              <p>
              <%= label_tag "Last Name" %>
              <%= text_field_tag :last_name %>
              <p/>
              <%= hidden_field_tag 'event_id', @event.id %>
              <p class="submit_register">
              <%= submit_tag "Register for this event" %>
                  <span class="help-block">Enter your name and email above and the link will be magically revealed</span>
              <p/>
            <%- end -%>
          </div>
        <%- end -%>
```

...with this coffeescript:

## events.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
    $(".location").hide()
    $(".submit_register").click ->
        $(".location").show()
        $(".registration_form").hide()
```

The issue I am having is `$(".location").hide()` in my coffeescript is being applied to all my events, however I only want it applied to events where `@event.requires_registration?` is `true`.

Comment: Conditionaly add a css class, with your js setup (without framework), difficult to do better.Btw, you should work on `submit` event on the form: people can submit it with enter, not only click

Comment: So I can add an if statement to my js `if form-group registration_form` is present...then `$(".location").hide()...`?

Comment: no, conditionaly add a class in your html and target it in your js

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/350087/apneadiving for leading me in the right direction. This worked for me...

```
jQuery ->
    if $('div').hasClass 'form-group registration_form'
        $(".location").hide()
        $(".submit_register").click ->
            $(".location").show()
            $(".registration_form").hide()
```